# Java: Common Annotation for "Not Yet Implemented"

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a common or standard annotation in Java for methods that, while defined, have yet to be implemented?

So that, for instance, if I were using a pre-alpha version of a library that contained something like

```
@NotImplementedYet
public void awesomeMethodThatTotallyDoesExactlyWhatYouNeed(){ /* TODO */ }
```

I'd get a compile-time warning when trying to call `awesomeMethodThatTotallyDoesExactlyWhatYouNeed`?

Comment: Most libraries simply won't expose that method at all.  What would be the point?

Comment: I've encountered it, [as a user](https://github.com/NICTA/scoobi/issues/71).  Maybe to float the future API as an idea, get users ready for it?

Comment: You could, of course, create your own "@NotImplementedYet" annotation, and use it however you want:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

Comment: Related: [*Is there anything like .NET's NotImplementedException in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2329358/642706)

Answer (score 19):

You might want to use [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) and detect calls to-yet-to-be-implemented methods when running your tests.

Comment: OP is looking for an annotation that will tell the caller at compile time that the method will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. As other side creating such an annotation is easy, he is looking for something that is accepted as convention

Comment: Not exactly the solution requested but better than nothing, and somewhat orthogonal (better in other ways).

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no standard annotation specifically for methods that have yet to be implemented.

However, there is a more general annotation in the JDK that marks an API which developers are discouraged from using, and the Java compiler itself can issue warnings when it is used. I am talking about `@Deprecated`, which many developers only think of as "announcing removal". However, the relevant articles in the JDK docs (e.g. for [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html) and [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/core/enhanced-deprecation1.htm)) list several example use cases, only one of them being about removal:

> - The API is dangerous (for example, the `Thread.stop` method).
> - There is a simple rename (for example, AWT `Component.show/hide` replaced by `setVisible`).
> - A newer, better API can be used instead.
> - The deprecated API is going to be removed.

I think your case "not implemented yet" certainly goes in the same direction as those. Further, if the method would always [throw a `NotYetImplementedException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50461711/7641), it even fits the example "The API is dangerous".

So all you need to do is the following:

1. Add `@Deprecated` to the method
2. Add `@deprecated` Javadoc to explain the background
3. Configure your build to invoke the compiler with `-Xlint:deprecation` so that it issues warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own annotation.  With the runtime retention policy you can then configure target builds to know to look for this annotation, if necessary.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({
    ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, 
    ElementType.METHOD, 
    ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
    ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Unimplemented {

    boolean value() default true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) libraries use the [@Beta](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/Beta.html) annotations for API that is likely to change but the methods are implemented though