# Java Dummy method body?

Tags: java, methods, interface, dummy-data

Is there any convention to use for a dummy method body in Java? for testing purposes for example. Say I have a interface and a method should be implemented in a class implementing that interface but I don't want to implement it yet, what good dummy method body should I use that doesn't use unnecessary memory etc?

Comment: For testing purpose, you can use mocking framework like Mockito.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984335/java-common-annotation-for-not-yet-implemented

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my apologies, my search yeld no results but then again I only searched for dummy method body and similar stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a method which you haven't implemented yet I would

```
public void notImplementedYet() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("TODO");
}
```

I add the `"TODO"` to indicate it may be supported in the future. Some methods throw this because it should never be supported.

BTW: I setup my IDE to place this exception as the default body for implementing methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8's default methods.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).
Basically, you define the implementation (or dummy method) in the interface itself.

```
public interface MyInterface {
   default myDummyMethod() {
      // nada
   }
}
```