# Can you have unimplemented java methods in your class body(similar to python pass)?

Tags: java

I'm writing a class and I find it helpful to have functions I have yet to implement in the class I'm working in, so if I'm making a stack for ints I could write something like:

```
public class Stack
{
    ...

    private void push(int n) {}

    private int pop() {}

    ...
}
```

just as a reminder of functionality I'm supporting and organizational purposes. Is this somehow possible? I keep getting compile time errors when I try.

The functionality I'm looking for is similar to python's pass statement like:

```
def f():
    pass
```

Comment: Not if you have a return type other than `void`. You could have just tried it.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607373/426028  Define your own NotImplementedException class and throw it from within your not-implemented methods.

Comment: Alternatively, comment out the line. Most IDE's make commenting easy; simply put your cursor in or highlight the line(s) you want to comment and press `ctrl  /` to toggle comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conventional way, which the Netbeans IDE will do automatically when implementing an interface or extending an abstract class to provide placeholders, is to do:

```
private void push(int n) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented yet");
}
```

Comment: +1 Eclipse uses default template of some variation of `return null;` which I think is a bad thing and usually replace my template by throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: Yeah, I haven't used eclipse for ages. I'll edit a specify netbeans since this is exactly what it does