# Can a class be instantiated as static in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Static Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844355/java-static-class)

Can a class be instantiated as static in java?

```
static class c1(){

}
```

Can this be done? I'm confused with this and memory mapping with non static stuff's. Please help

Answer (score 10):

The significance of `static` with a class definition is not whether the class can be instantiated or not, but rather whether the class must be instantiated from within a non-static method of the outer class or not.

Non-static inner class instances are tied to the instance that created them -- there's a pointer in the inner class instance back to the creating instance (which is useful in a number of ways).  Static inner class instances are not tied to the creating instance.

(I worked in the innards of the JVM for about 10 years and I still find this confusing.)

Comment: "Static inner class instances are not tied to the creating instance."  This is what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

> Can the class be instantiated with the static keyword in java ? eg : static class c1(){ }

Your terminology is incorrect.  "Instantiating a class" means creating an instance of the class; i.e. *creating an object*.  This is done using the `new` operation.  Your example is really about *declaring* a class.

Having said that, yes you can declare a class as `static`, but this can only done for a nested class; i.e. a class declared *inside* another class.

> am confused with this and the memory mapping with non static stuff's please help

I haven't a clue what you are talking about here.  If you need more help on this point, you will need to explain yourself more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

static doesn't have anything to do with memory mapping.  It means there is no instance it is associated with.

For a `static class` it means instances of the class are not associated with an outer class instance.

Answer (score 0):

It breaks the paradigms. Consider this one: Static members are members that every instance has in common, but its not clear how to extend this idea of shared to a class?

What did you expect the static keyword to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can have static class as shown below

```
class A
{
static class B   //static inner class
    {
     static void dis()
      {
      System.out.println("this is me");
      }
    }
}

class four extends A.B
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    dis();

    }
}
```

Comment: In the above xample ..an mulitple level inheritance is tnstantiated ...is that possible in JAVA ?