# Utility class with Project-Wide functions

Tags: vb.net, oop, global

I have a class with a load of methods and properties that will be used in multiple classes across the whole project. I don't want to have to instantiate an instance of this, that doesn't make any sense to me, but what is the best way to go about this?

I know in Java you could have a class marked with final and have a private constructor and static methods, as per this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844355/java-static-class). Is there a designated way of doing the same thing in **vb.net** that I'm missing?

Comment: Arvo's answer is correct but I'd strongly consider breaking those utilities out into their own classes or at the very least multiple modules of like utilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.NET, you can use Module instead of Class, internally it means something like public static/shared class.