# Using AssertionError and assertions in java

Tags: java, exception, assertions

I use assertions in Java in a standard way, having them turned on in my IDE. So they are not part of production release. Lately I have been seeing code examples with `throw new AssertionError()` and I started thinking about the situation where `AssertionError` should be used instead of assertion.

My guess is that main difference is the optionality of asserts so they don't slow down the production performance and so they can occur quite often in the code, but fixing  hardly reproducible bugs reported from users is harder.

For `AssertionError`, the exact opposite applies.

I also find `AssertionError` more practical in places in code where the execution should not get, instead of using `assert false //We should not be here`. Especially if the return value is required. For example:

```
int getFoo(AnEnum a){
    if (a == AnEnum.ONE)
       return bar();
    else if (a == AnEnum.TWO)
       return SOME_VALUE;
    //else
    assert false; //throw new AssertionError();
    return -1; //not necessary when usin AssertionError
}
```

- Is my reasoning correct?
- What are the other differences/use cases/best practices/limitations
  of either approach?
- In regards to providing a description in the `AssertionError` - Should it be provided or is the mere fact that it is an `Error` (and
  of assertion type) enough to be more or less sure that stack trace
  will be provided in case of found bugs?

Comment: How often are your assertions *actually* slow? Personally I like to keep my seat-belt when I'm driving in the real world, rather than only when learning :) (In fact, it's much more important to fail fast in production code than in test code - if you keep going having arrived at an invalid state, you may well wipe real production data.) Consider only removing assertions when you have *evidence* that they're slowing your program down in a significant way.

Comment: Basically you are correct.  Although some want assertions removed from production code since invalid behavior is viewed as better than outright application failure.  And it's probably a good idea to provide at least a basic error description with the AssertionError, so that first-level debugging can be done without having to dig through the source files (and in case some bozo only reports the error message, without stack trace).

Comment: @JonSkeet But you could just leave assertions on for that part of the code. With `AssertionError` you don't have any option, it's thrown even if assertions have been deliberately disabled.

Comment: @HotLicks You can give a reason code with the `assert false "Should not be reached"` as well, so that does not distinguish between `assert false` and `throw AssertionError()`.

Comment: Your example is not valid if `getFoo` is publicly reachable, according to the Java technote ["Programming With Assertions"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage)

Comment: If I could make breaking changes to java, the constructors to Throwable and all the errors would be package private.  Then we would not be having this conversation.

Answer (score 7):

In the technote ["Programming With Assertions: Control Flow Invariants"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage-control) the following code is given:

```
void foo() {
    for (...) {
      if (...)
        return;
    }
    assert false; // Execution should never reach this point!
}
```

But the following note is given as well:

> Note: Use this technique with discretion. If a statement is unreachable as defined in the Java Language Specification, you will get a compile time error if you try to assert that it is not reached. Again, an acceptable alternative is simply to throw an AssertionError.

---

You may not expect an `AssertionError` to be thrown when assertions are turned off. As `AssertionError` constructors are public, and since there is likely no substitution for `AssertionError(String message, Throwable cause)`, I guess that you *should* expect them even if they are turned off.

---

Throwing an `AssertionError` on unreachable code (i.e. without any real expression to be evaluated) will never slow down the code, as Jon Skeet suggested, so it won't hurt with regards to performance.

---

So in the end throwing the `AssertionError` seems OK.

Comment: Only found the comment *after* generating the bounty, other answers welcome, of course.

Comment: I thought that a more descriptive exception class name than AssertionError was CoderMalfunctionError. Alas, that refers to the charset encoder rather than the coder in front of the keyboard! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I would advise against throwing `AssertionError`s directly. If you choose to rely on `AssertionError`s for checking invariants, pre/post conditions, state conditions, etc. you're still better off using regular assertions with the "-ea" flag turned on in production as well.
The reason is that the assertions mechanism (other than being optimized at the compiler level) gives you a chance to turn on or off all assertions at once. Even if you can't think of a reason to do that now, if you come across a reason in the future, just consider that you'll have to go over all your `throw new AssertionError(...)` type code and surround it with a nasty `if` clause. You get the picture.
Just as you wouldn't want a magic number hard coded into many places in your code, and would probably use a constant instead, you shouldn't infect your code with many duplications (i.e. the `throw new AssertionError(...)` part).

Another word about assertions though. I believe that you should think twice before relying on assertion errors in production code. The reason is that an `AssertionError` is very generic. It has a message and a cause, but that's pretty much it.
Consider instead using specific `RuntimeException` subclasses that will convey more information both by being of a specific class more related to the problem, as well as by carrying actual data related to the problem.
As a simple example, consider a case you mentioned in your question where there's some part of the code that you don't expect to reach. An assertion or an `AssertionError` would convey the fact that you reached some unexpected code, but not much more. Using a specific `RuntimeException` could also deliver the state of the local variables and parameters of the method at that point in time. You could argue that this is doable with setting the message of the assertion or `AssertionError` to contain this information, but this does not work when using automatic error logging/handling mechanisms. Such mechanisms can handle unexpected behaviors using the visitor pattern on the different sub classes of `RuntimeException` you're using to check unexpected behavior (by handle I also mean fail-fast, not necessarily recovery).

Comment: I agree largely with your assessment (probably more than with the answer I gave), however the answer I've written is from Sun/Oracle documentation. So I can only conclude that *according to Technote* it is OK, if it wasn't allowed, the constructors *should have been hidden*. Besides that, choosing between `assert false` and `new Error` for unreachable code (where the first one is not seen as an exit point) is choosing between two evils. I agree with you that the error is bad, but having to use `return null` or similar is equally bad.