# May I throw an AssertionError in an EJB method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, error-handling, ejb

Following the style used in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java and in agreement with the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863185/what-is-an-assertionerror-in-which-case-should-i-throw-it-from-my-own-code) question, I've used AssertionErrors in the past in the Java SE environment for code paths that should never possibly be executed.

Looking at Java EE, the EJB 3.1 specification says

> If the bean method encounters a system exception or error, it should simply propagate the error from the bean method to the container (i.e., the bean method does not have to catch the exception).

and a little further down, it says that the concerned EJB instance has to be discarded in the case of a non-ApplicationException. As far as I know, if another instance of that EJB is required in a subsequent request, the container takes one from the pool or creates a new one if necessary, so there should be no problems associated with that (except of course if it was a @Singleton EJB).

Is it appropriate/good style to use an AssertionError in a session bean method for indicating programming errors? Or is there a more fitting Throwable subtype for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see anything wrong in throwing an `AssertionError`. The container should be able to perform a rollback, just as it would for any unckecked exceptions.

Having said that, I never throw `AssertionError`s myself. A couple of common examples where I would throw a subclass of `RuntimeException`, which is probably more appropriate than `AssertionError`, are:

Say we have an `enum`:

```
public enum TestEnum {
  TEST1, TEST2;
}
```

I want to catch the default case, in this I throw an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
public class TestClass {

  public void doSomethingWithTestEnum(TestEnum testEnum) {
    switch (testEnum) {
    case TEST1:
      // do something here
      break;
    case TEST2:
      // do something here
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown enum type: " + testEnum);
    }
  }

}
```

Another example would be parameter validation:

```
public class TestClass {

  private String testString;

  public TestClass(String testString) {
    this.testString = Objects.requireNonNull(testString);
  }

}
```

Here, a `NullPointerException` is thrown if `testString` is null.

There are probably cases where an assertion would be more suitable, but honestly I never encounter them.

Comment: I was mostly concerned that an Error could affect the container negatively somehow, but like you say, that should be no problem.

As for using `AssertionError`s, switches on `Enum`s with a missing case for one of the values is actually one of the examples where Joshua Bloch does use it. ;-) I guess it depends on the kind of the Enum, but if it is one that has a lot of "semantic" meaning, not accounting for one of the possible values could be regarded as more of a programming error.