# Why java.util.Objects private constructor throws assertionError

Tags: java

I have observed that java.util.Objects has a constructor which is throwing AssertionError.

```
 * @since 1.7
 */
public final class Objects {
    private Objects() {
        throw new AssertionError("No java.util.Objects instances for you!");
    }
 ...
```

This is a static utility class and hence no instance needed.

One possible reason I understand is, the developer is trying to ensure that no instance of this class is created. As the only way anyone can call this constructor is by reflection.

Is there any other reason to have this kind of constructor?

Comment: I don't know.  I guess serialization?  But also it sends a stronger message than just, say, saying in the Java doc that the constructor is something that should never be called.

Comment: @markspace Deserialization does not invoke constructors.

Comment: What do you mean by "this kind of constructor" - what's your suggested alternative? Just having the private constructor which does nothing?

Comment: Not really, I am asking if my understand is correct about having such constructor which ensures no object of that class are created in any way possible.

Comment: Seeing this, I would indeed assume it is to protect against reflection

Comment: @icza Serialization invokes the default constructor of the nearest non-serializable base class, but this class is final and non-serializable, so Serialization doesn't apply at all.

Comment: I love the Seinfeld reference! It's the java.util.Objects instance Nazi!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The sole purpose is to enforce noninstantiability. Since it is `private`, the `AssertionError` is mainly for reflection and for the *class itself* because private constructors can be called from the class itself. And as a side effect, this idiom also prevents the class from being subclassed.

Quoting from Effective Java 2nd Edition Item 4:

```
// Noninstantiable utility class
public class UtilityClass {
    // Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
    private UtilityClass() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
    ... // Remainder omitted
}
```

> Because the explicit constructor is private, it is inaccessible outside of the
>   class. The AssertionError isn’t strictly required, but it provides insurance in
>   case the constructor is accidentally invoked from within the class. It guarantees
>   that the class will never be instantiated under any circumstances. This idiom is
>   mildly counterintuitive, as the constructor is provided expressly so that it cannot
>   be invoked. It is therefore wise to include a comment, as shown above.
>   As a side effect, this idiom also prevents the class from being subclassed. All
>   constructors must invoke a superclass constructor, explicitly or implicitly, and a
>   subclass would have no accessible superclass constructor to invoke.

Also you might find this Question useful:

[What is the preferred Throwable to use in a private utility class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398953/what-is-the-preferred-throwable-to-use-in-a-private-utility-class-constructor)

Comment: Thanks @icza. The quote was helpful. So now I believe it is a design best practice.

Comment: I'd also make the class final, in order to prohibit subclassing at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

They just created this private constructor to ensure that nobody can instantiate this class. And to prevent an instantiation using reflection, the error is thrown. So I think your understanding of this construct is correct ;)